# Will code after eval(die "some error message") continue to be executed?

Tags: perl, eval, die

I know that in java language ,if an exception is catched successfully ,the code after the try-catch-clause will still run.In perl ,it uses eval to catch exception.So ,I write two simple programs to test it.

testEval1.pl:

```
 $exp = '$i = 3; die "error message"; $k = $i + $j';

push ( @program, '$i = 3; die "error message"; $k = $i + $j');
 $rtn =eval($exp);
    if ( ! defined ( $rtn))
    {
       print "Exception: " , $@,"\n";
    }
    else
    {
       print $rtn,"\n";
    }
```

output of testEval1.pl:

```
code continue to run after die!
Exception: error message at (eval 1) line 1.
```

testEval2.pl

```
$baseDir = "/home/wuchang/newStore1";
my $eval_rtn = eval(opendir(BASEDIR,$baseDir) or die "dir doesn't exist!\n");
print "code continue to run after die!\n";
if(!defined($eval_rtn)){
print $@;
}
 else
    {
       print $rtn,"\n";
    }
```

output of testEval2.pl:

```
dir doesn't exist!
```

you can see that in the two code examples , the code block of eval both has die expressions.But in testEval1.pl,the code after eval can be excuted,while in testEval2.pl,it's not!
So ,my question is ,what's the difference ?
What can I do to make the program continue to run even if a "dir doesn't exist" exception happeded ?

thank you.

Comment: If you want slightly more Java-like `try-catch` syntax, check out the [`Try::Tiny` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny).

Comment: Thank you for your notification.It is useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're evaling result of

```
opendir(BASEDIR,$baseDir) or die "dir doesn't exist!\n"
```

code. If it would succeed that would be equivalent of `eval(1)`.

What you want is `eval BLOCK`:

```
my $eval_rtn = eval{ opendir(BASEDIR,$baseDir) or die "dir doesn't exist!\n" };
```

Check [perldoc -f eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) for difference between `eval EXPR` and `eval BLOCK`

Comment: So ,for $rtn =eval($exp); it is the kind of eval BLOCK or eval EXPR ?May I conclude that since $exp is surrounded by a single-quote,so it is kind of eval BLOCK?right?

Comment: @Vico_Wu consider eval with braces: `eval{ .. }` as eval BLOCK, and everything else as eval EXPR.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question title:

> Will code after eval(die “some error message”) continue to be executed?

The answer is "No". But please read on, because this is not a problem, but a misunderstanding about the Perl syntax involved.

The line:

```
my $eval_rtn = eval( opendir(BASEDIR,$baseDir) or die "dir doesn't exist!\n" );
```

Does not get as far as running the `eval`. The syntax you have used with `(..)` brackets takes a scalar value, and before the `eval` does anything at all, it is waiting for the `opendir...or die` expression to return a string (which will then be evaluated). To make it equivalent to your other example, you could make the param a string:

```
my $eval_rtn = eval( q{opendir(BASEDIR,$baseDir) or die "dir doesn't exist!\n"} );
```

You could also use the block form instead:

```
my $eval_rtn = eval { opendir(BASEDIR,$baseDir) or die "dir doesn't exist!\n"; };
```

I would recommend using the block form where possible, it is usually easier to debug, and in your case better matches the exception handling semantics that you want to achieve.

Comment: So,for expression eval( opendir(BASEDIR,$baseDir) or die "dir doesn't exist!\n" );,eval just get a string as an param and thus working the same as eval(1)?

Comment: @Vico_Wu: Yes. Although `opendir` will return something other than `1` if successful, that is the basic issue.